# How to know if a computer is being used remotely

Tags: windows-10, powershell, remote-desktop, python, c#

Is there a way to know that a computer (win10) is currently being controlled remotely? (via RDP)

-And if so, can I know the user-name connected to it?

I have several computers that me and my coworkers connect to via RDP,
and I would like to have a way to tell which computer is "occupied" so no one will log into it by mistake, and disconnect me (or someone else)

- all computers are connected to the company's domain

the idea is to create a "list" of available workstations so there will not be any conflict between the team member's workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: They could just attempt to connect - it will then tell them if someone (without telling who it is) is logged in - and they can choose to connect anyway or not. If they choose to connect anyway - it will then show the username of the person logged in - and waiting for 30 seconds. If the user is active - they will get a prompt some other username is trying to login and can choose to allow, or reject. This won't work if you are sharing a user/pass.

Comment: I agree that this is what should happen, but at the current setup, the currently connected user just get "thrown" out of the system, so the new user doesn't even know that someone is (was) connected (idk why this happens but it is what it is....). 
so my question is, is it possible to know prior to connecting? :)

Comment: You could check with `qwinsta /server:$computer`, where $computer is the iterating variable on a list of computers. If that reveals a username with a status of `Active`, the computer is 'occupied'

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I've ran the command and it shows that my user is active even if I'm not connected to that computer - I think it just shows if MY user is active on that computer (doesn't matter if logged in at the moment or not) * it also shows only MY user. (maybe its a domain authorization issue?)

Comment: Remote access to your computer is disabled by default unless you give that user that access specifically.  Have you done that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are referring to MY personal computer - in that matter,  RDP access is enabled (as sys admins configured).

But, I'm trying to check for activity on the remote computers prior RDP-ing to THEM, and not to my personal computer.